# spacing between bars in a histogram in r

Tags: r, histogram

I have this problem: when I try to graph a histogram it appears with space between the bars when it shouldn't, here is the graph:

[image]

Those zeros shouldn't be there, the variable table I'm plotting is:

[image]

This is the code to make the histogram that I am using:

```
hist(x= ae18$v_histo_acpm,main = "Histogram,labels = TRUE,
 xlab = "No. de cambios al mes", ylab = "Frecuencia")
```

Comment: The problem is that a barplot might be more adapted to your data. Try `barplot(table(ae18$v_histo_acpm))` instead.

Comment: I think @VincentGuillemot is right, that a barplot is a better display.  You could get what you want using `hist() with `hist(a20185$v_histo_acpm, breaks=seq(.5, 9.5, by=1))`